# Android Scroller Listener

Tags: java, android

need help, I don't know what to do.

I use the [android-verticalpager library](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager)

Need to catch the moment when scrolling to the next screen over.

Down here you can see

```
pager.addOnScrollListener(new VerticalPager.OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScroll(int scrollX) {
        //Log.d("TestActivity", "scrollX=" + scrollX);
    }

    public void onViewScrollFinished(int currentPage) {
        //Log.d("TestActivity", "viewIndex=" + currentPage);
    }
});
```

And, ([this is here](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager/blob/master/src/com/grantlandchew/view/VerticalPager.java))

```
int adjustedScrollY = getScrollY() + pageHeightPadding();
mListener.onScroll(adjustedScrollY);
if (adjustedScrollY % pageHeight == 0) {
    mListener.onViewScrollFinished(adjustedScrollY / pageHeight);
}
```

The problem is that onViewScrollFinished is only when we see the first screen.

As far as I understand the problem in the sense of the page height.

I ask your help, I will be very grateful! How to catch the moment when the animation is completed?

Sorry, my english very bad.